# Appcelerator [ERROR] : certificate has expired

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I want to build an Android app I get this error:

```
result from /build-verify=> {"success":false,"error":"certificate has expired","code":"com.appcelerator.security.invalid.module.verification"}, err=null
[ERROR] :  certificate has expired
```

It happens with new created projects and with old ones. I tried appc logout / app login, same results
I'm using **6.0.0 SDK** on osx.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I updated my studio and my SDK and now is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following commands and it worked for me. First close Appcelerator Studio, then execute the following commands in terminal.

```
appc logout -D
appc login
```

After that relaunch Appcelerator Studio and try to build again.